# add all edittexts data of listview in arraylist

Tags: android

I have a list view containing textview and edit texts and i have to add these values in array list.As i am trying it not all values are added to Arraylist,only values of that particular visible view gets added.How should I modify my code so that all the data gets added to arraylist.

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
flags=0;
getData();
placeord=(Button)findViewById(R.id.placeorder);

placeord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(isNetworkConnected()) {
            ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> si = new ArrayList<String>();
            EditText q;
            TextView sizes;

            for (int i =0; i<= list.getLastVisiblePosition() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
                View  v = list.getChildAt(i);
                q = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.numberofitems);
                sizes = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.size);

                if(q.getText().toString().length()>0) {

                    si.add(sizes.getText().toString());
                    flags=1;

                }
                m.add(q.getText().toString());
            }

            if (flags == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please add some quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),val,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(placecolor.this, placeorder2.class);
                Bundle extras1 = new Bundle();
                extras1.putStringArrayList("numberofitems", m);
                extras1.putStringArrayList("sizes", si);
                intent.putExtras(extras1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Total list view count is

 int count=lstView.getAdapter().getCount();

Comment: how would getting count help...

Comment: for (int i =0; i <= lstView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) I think that's what he meant?

Comment: i added this before but it get unfortunately stop because I guess list.getchildat was giving null pointer exception,so I changed the code

Comment: Yeah because getChildAt only gives the "view" childs not the actual ones. I suggest @SANAT answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because android recycle the view of **ListView** and **Recyclerview**. You need to add(save) data of **EditText** by implementing **OnTextChangeListener**. By implementing it you can get the entered text and assign it to particular position in List<>.

**Example :**

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_list, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);    

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ref = position;

        holder.textView.setText(arr[position].name);
        holder.editText.setText(arr[position].nameValue);
        holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arr[holder.ref].nameValue = arg0.toString(); // Set value in list
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain with an example.

Comment: @user6704378 check the example.

Comment: @user6704378 is it helpful?

Comment: @user6704378 Accept this answer, if it helps you.